# Kotlin ViewModel List of String

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and ViewModel uses.
I am trying to create a simple ViewModel which got a List of String.
The idea is to update a list a picture path (String) in this ViewModel.

My issue is that my ViewModel is not updating. It only add 1 entry.

```
class PicturesViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var pictureListLive: MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>> = MutableLiveData()

    var list = ArrayList<String>()

    fun addPictureToList(picture: String) {
        list.add(picture)
        pictureListLive.value = list
    }
}
```

In my activity I initialize the viewModel and observe like that :

```
 private fun configureViewModel(){
        this.picturesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PicturesViewModel::class.java!!)
        this.picturesViewModel.pictureListLive.observe(this, Observer{
            if (it != null) {
                Log.i("Pictures",it.size.toString())
            }
        })
    }
```

And I add one String to the ViewModel :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            picturesViewModel.addPictureToList(currentPhotoPath)
            val intentPreview = Intent(this,PreviewActivity::class.java)
            intentPreview.putExtra("Picture",currentPhotoPath)
            startActivity(intentPreview)}

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CHOOSE_PHOTO){
            this.pictureSelectedPath = data?.data.toString()
            Log.i("Photo",pictureSelectedPath)
        }
    }
```

The ActivityOnResult come from after taking a picture to the camera. I want to update the list of String of the ViewModel to add the picture camera path after taking few pictures.

When I am using it like that today the Size of the ViewModel list remains to 1. I think only the last one is in it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you pass the code on the Fragment/Activity where you are initializing viewmodel ?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. I suggest you read a little bit more about Kotlin and the usage of viewmodels, `LiveData` and more before you start coding anything.

Comment: Note related to the question but here are my advices to your code > First your `setPictureList()` should not have a return value, Second your `getPictureList()` should return `LiveData` rather than `MutableLiveData`. You can get rid this code `pictureListLive.value = pictureList` in your `getPictureList()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a use case in initializing and using a simple ViewModel

```
//in your pictures fragment
private lateinit var picturesViewModel: PicturesViewModel
```

than in your `onCreate`

`picturesViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PicturesViewModel::class.java)`

After you have initialized the viewmodel , you may observe data changes that happen there , below the initialisation of course:

```
picturesViewModel.pictureListLive.observe(this, Observer {
            //list changes are handled here 
        })
```

If I were to rewrite you ViewModelClass it would be like this :

```
class PictureViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var pictureListLive: MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>> = MutableLiveData()


    fun setPictureList(picture: String) {
       val list = ArrayList<String>()
       list.add(picture)
       pictureListLive.value = list 
    }
}
```

There is no need to return a list because the MutableLiveData work in the publish-subscribe logic , aka the Observable Pattern .

This is similar like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or RxJava [operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html)

**Note**

I would need more information about that `setPictureList` method because like that it doesn't have much sense . Or maybe you wanna call it somewhere else or idk .

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. The setPictureList function is to update the list of Picture path by adding a new one to the ViewModel. The problem here is that the the list is inside the setPictureList so when adding a new picture String than the PictureListLive will only have one entry. This should be called addPictureList for better understanding.

Comment: I have set your method to my application. I wanted to use the ViewModel in another activity. To Glide the picture path in a recyclerview. I think I have some issue. The ViewModel seems empty. There are not update in the other activity.

Comment: please update the question with your problem . and I will be updating the answer . Please let me know also

Comment: that is because the ViewModel has a lifecycle together with activity/fragment . when you open camera activity and than reopen your fragment where your list is , the array list gets initialized again `var list = ArrayList<String>()`

Comment: In this case how do you avoid the new initialization ?

Comment: you must keep the current list somewhere saved and then add data to it

Answer (score 2):

On April 10, 2021 in **Android Studio 4.1.3 Kotlin 1.4.32** **compileSdkVersion 30.0.3**
possible solution:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2"
}
```

Code in AppCompatActivity: Creat ViewModel:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val picturesViewModel: PicturesViewModel by viewModels()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    picturesViewModel.pictureListLive.observe(this, {
       it?.let { Log.i("Pictures", "size =  ${it.size} ${if (it.size>0) it[it.size-1] 
       else "empty"}") }
    })
}
```

Calling app Camera and returning the result

```
private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // There are no request codes
    val data: Intent? = result.data
    val path = result?.data?.getStringExtra(PATH) ?:"sssss"
    picturesViewModel.addPictureToList(path)
  }
}

fun onClick(view: View) {
    val questionIntent = Intent(this, Camera::class.java)
    // new call for startActivityForResult:
    resultLauncher.launch(questionIntent)    }
 }
```

PicturesViewModel.kt:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class PicturesViewModel : ViewModel() {

var pictureListLive: MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>> =
    MutableLiveData(mutableListOf())

    fun addPictureToList(picture: String) {
     pictureListLive.value?.add(picture)
     // so that the observer can see that the list has changed
     pictureListLive.value = pictureListLive.value
    }
  }
```

Result:

```
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  0 empty
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  1 123Path
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  2 234Path
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  3 Path345
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  4 Pa456th
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  5 Pa567th
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  6 Path678
2021-04-10 com.example.kotlinviewmodellistofstring I/Pictures: size =  7 cam123456
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thats pretty weird that Android has no generic solution for this, maybe like MutableCollection<T> with adding, removing etc.